# what's the right way to request events on Google Calendar by filtering on some fields?

Tags: javascript, google-api, calendar

I'm trying some google calendar api's on [event list explorer](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

How can i retrieve a specific event with some filtering methods?
Example: I'd like to list an event with a particular id. Do i need to use privateExtendedProperty/sharedExtendedProperty? 
THX

Answer (score 0):

If you have the event id you should use [event.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)

Beyond that event.list has a q parameter which will allow you to search

> q  string  Free text search terms to find events that match these terms in any field, except for extended properties. Optional.

Comment: ok but i need to list all events in primary calendar filtering on id with specific pattern. E.g all events with id starting with "blabla" ---> it should returns event1 with id "blabla2344", event2 with id "blabla3545463" and so on

Comment: Something like that is not supported by the API.